# Setting default values for arbitrary number of keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say I have:

`class Example(object):`

```
    def __init__(self, table = None, rows = None, cats = None, **kwargs)
        self.table = table
        self.rows = rows
        self.cats = cats
```

My question is, how can I make kwargs have a default value of None, for all the kwargs? kwargs is a dict, right...?

Comment: You can check for the existence of the needed key in kwargs and assign None if it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That makes no sense. The reason to use `kwargs` at all is because you're not sure what keyword arguments are going to be passed in. So what would it mean for an unknown keyword argument to have a default value?

You can use a default when you ask for a value from `kwargs` by simply using the dictionary `.get()` method, if that's what you're asking:

```
value_that_might_be_missing = kwargs.get('myvalue', 'mydefault')
```

otherwise I really can't imagine what you would want.

Comment: Some context: I have a class that takes some data for use later...but I want to be able to take an arbitrary amount of data later on but be able to manipulate it based on what it is.

Comment: so while I don't know how many unknown keyword arguments I'll get, i do know I want them all to have an initial value of None.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is a dictionary. As such, it supports the [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method. Just like using `[]` but will return `None` (or a custom value) instead of raising a `KeyError`.